# weblogic server fails to publish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, webserver

When I start my weblogic server though the server starts it always fails to publish, below is the exception trace found from errorlog.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:783)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1433)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:896)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:677)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3029)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Contains: Deployment operation was not completed within timeout. State Type : running; Command Type : distribute; Action Type  : execute; Completed  : false; Failed : false; Message : null; Exception : null
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue when required jars were missing. Please recheck whether your dependencies are getting bundled properly. If not, try to look in eclipse logfile for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar exception when my web.xml file couldn't find my servlet.  I had changed the package name the servlet was in and the web.xml file wasn't updated.